# Customising line thickness of each line mapped in R using tmap package?

Tags: r

I have generated a map showing the intensity of burglaries that have occurred on a street segment. I have used the tmap package from R to generate the desired street-level map. The codes are as follows:

```
   map.burglary =  tm_shape(street.crime.rates.lines) + 
                   tm_lines(col = "b_rates",
                            style = "fixed", 
                            breaks = c(0, 1, 10, 20, 50, 500),
                            labels = c("<1.0", "1.0-9.9", "10.0-19.9","20.0", 49.9", "50.0+"),
                            textNA = "Unavailable",
                            colorNA = "gray87",
                            title.col = c("Burglary (per 10 households)")) +
                   tm_compass(type = "8star", position = c("right","top")) +
                   tm_scale_bar(breaks = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)) +
                   tm_layout(frame = TRUE, legend.title.size = 0.8, legend.outside = TRUE, legend.outside.position = "right")
    map.burglary
```

The resulting output:

[image]

I want to increase the line thickness of each line as the intensity of burglaries represented on the map becomes larger. I want this detail to be reflected in the map and legends. Does anyone know how to code this in R using the tmap package?

Comment: Does the standard lwd argument not work?

Comment: It works, but it increases the size of all lines. I want to assign different lwd's that are specify to each of the lines that are represented in the map (and legends). If I try something like ... lwd = c(1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 2),... in the tm_lines function it literally splits the image into 5 separate maps which is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the name of the variable in the thing being plotted, not the values. For example with data like this:

```
> m@data
          name            type scalerank strokelwd
5  Mississippi Lake Centerline         5       2.0
6  Mississippi Lake Centerline         5       2.5
7  Mississippi           River         5       1.5
```

you'd use:

```
tm_shape(m) + tm_lines(lwd="strokelwd")
```

producing:

[image]